# Downloading a File Using a Service

Tags: java, android

I have app for download apk file from server with `ProgressDialog`, and trying to that gets updated. But if click button download the app crashes and get an error in the following line and download doesn't start. If I delete all code of `ProgressDialog` also download doesn't start and crashes the app. Why? Help me please.

```
progressDialog.show();
```

My `DownloadService.java`

```
public class DownloadService extends IntentService {
    public static final int UPDATE_PROGRESS = 8344;
    public DownloadService() {
        super("DownloadService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        String urlToDownload = intent.getStringExtra("url");
        ResultReceiver receiver = (ResultReceiver) intent.getParcelableExtra("receiver");
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlToDownload);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            // this will be useful so that you can show a typical 0-100% progress bar
            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

            // download the file
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/debug.apk");

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            long total = 0;
            int count;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                Bundle resultData = new Bundle();
                resultData.putInt("progress" ,(int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                receiver.send(UPDATE_PROGRESS, resultData);
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Bundle resultData = new Bundle();
        resultData.putInt("progress" ,100);
        receiver.send(UPDATE_PROGRESS, resultData);
    }
}
```

And the activity is..

```
public class new_app extends AppCompatActivity {

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_app);


        Button down2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.down);
        down2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View view) {
                progressDialog.show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Emoji11ios.this, DownloadService.class);
                intent.putExtra("url", "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/14rzjsl26zf0mqf/SCR%20Screen%20Recorder%20Pro%20V0.21.7.apk");
                intent.putExtra("receiver", new DownloadReceiver(new Handler()));
                startService(intent);
                    }
        });
    }

    private class DownloadReceiver extends ResultReceiver {
        public DownloadReceiver(Handler handler) {
            super(handler);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
            super.onReceiveResult(resultCode, resultData);
            if (resultCode == DownloadService.UPDATE_PROGRESS) {
                int progress = resultData.getInt("progress");
                progressDialog.setProgress(progress);
                if (progress == 100) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId()==android.R.id.home)
            finish();
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here's the `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true">
    <activity android:name=".maActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".preview_update"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme_new" />

    <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service android:name=".DownloadService" >
    </service>
</application>
```

Finally the logcat

```
03-24 22:13:30.445 2166-2166/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
03-24 22:13:30.446 2166-2166/? E/libpersona: scanKnoxPersonas
03-24 22:13:30.446 2166-2166/? E/libpersona: Couldn't open the File - /data/system/users/0/personalist.xml - No such file or directory
03-24 22:13:36.558 2166-2166/com.testapp4s.down E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: com.testapp4s.down, PID: 2166
                                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ProgressDialog.show()' on a null object reference
                                                                          at com.testapp4s.down.preview_update.new_app $2.onClick(new_app .java:116)
                                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6896)
                                                                          at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:12651)
                                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26088)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6940)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: Please post your logcat.

Comment: done ..plz check

Comment: This is a `NullPointerException`, which indicates your `ProgressDialog` was not initialized.

Comment: how can solve ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not initialized your `ProgressDialog` in your `new_app` activity. So in your `onCreate` function, you need to initialize it like the following. Check the comment where you need to initialize it.

```
public class new_app extends AppCompatActivity {

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_app);

        // You need to initialize it here. 
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        Button down2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.down);
        down2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View view) {
                progressDialog.show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Emoji11ios.this, DownloadService.class);
                intent.putExtra("url", "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/14rzjsl26zf0mqf/SCR%20Screen%20Recorder%20Pro%20V0.21.7.apk");
                intent.putExtra("receiver", new DownloadReceiver(new Handler()));
                startService(intent);

                    }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Great to hear that I could help. Thanks.